# determine the current precision/epsilon of a floating point variable

Tags: c, double-precision, epsilon

I am trying to separate two doubles of equal value by the minimum amount.  The context is an event simulation.  I don't want events to occur at the same time, so I increment the time that a new event is set to occur, by a minimal amount.

(This happens annoyingly often (self-implemented RNG), so I actually need to probe until I find a time when there isn't an event occurring.)

Currently, my code wants to do something like this
(not tested, treat as pseudocode):

```
typedef struct event 
 { 
   double time;
   struct event* nexteventinqueue;
 } event;
//insert newevent into the queue:
void add(event *newevent)
{
static event *firsteventinqueue = NULL;
if(firsteventinqueue == NULL)
{
    firsteventinqueue = newevent;
    return;
}
event *currentevent = firsteventinqueue;
event *temp;
//find an event point in the queue that does not precede the new event.
while((currentevent->time) < (newevent -> time))
{
    temp = currentevent;
    currentevent = currentevent->nexteventinqueue;
}
if(currentevent == NULL)//no such event found, so tag it onto the end.
{
    temp->next = newevent;
    return;
}
//handle coincidences by delaying the new event
while((currentevent->time) == (newevent->time))
{
    double d = (maximally precise increment of a double precision floating point number);
    while((currentevent->time) == (newevent.time)) //loop I want to get rid of
    {
        newevent.time += d;
        d *= 2;
    }
    temp = currentevent;
    currentevent = currentevent.nexteventinqueue;
}
temp.nexteventinqueue = newevent;
newevent.nexteventinqueue = currentevent;
return;
}
```

Now there are quite a few issues with this, but I want to somehow get rid of the while loop in the middle.  Most of my times aren't even close to holding the maximum precision that a double floating point can muster, so it's a waste of time to start by assuming they do, and because my RNG isn't especially random, this loop must execute quite frequently.

Is there a way to either 
(1) directly increment the fractional part of a double floating point variable, or to
(2) figure out how precise a given floating point variable x in less than O(log(x))?

Comment: Normally discrete event engines support events at the same time. The important thing is to ensure that when that happens there is a defined order of execution. Usually that means last scheduled is last executed, which gives almost the same behaviour you have without tinkering with the time.

Comment: Never use `double` for time. For floating point you get variable precision (larger values are less precise), and it ends up being very wrong for most purposes (e.g. "2_years + 1_second = 2_years"). Instead use an integer where the precision is constant (e.g. maybe `uint64_t` depending on the range and precision you want).

Comment: @Keith: What you are saying makes perfect sense, but it violates one of the assumptions of a poisson process, so some might object out of principle.  (There are other, worse violations of those assumptions going on in this case, though.)

Comment: @Brendan: Ah, just have the integer represent some power-of-2 fraction of a second!  Brilliant!  Thank you.

Comment: @morescientistthancoderfornow: I typically go with something like "64-bit nanoseconds since the epoch" (which is good enough to handle about 584 years, with more precision than most things need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nextafter` (from `<math.h>`) to get the immediately next largest value after a double-precision value. (Or `nextafterf` for a single-precision value).

For more information, `man nextafter`, also [available here.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nextafter)

Comment: So the precision would be `nextafter(currentevent->time, ((double)1/0)) ) - (currentevent->time)`?

Comment: You might have problems with `(double)1/0`, that's going to be a rather large number that will need to be trapped. Any number greater than `currentevent->time` will cause `nextafter` to return the next representable value larger than `currentevent->time`.

Comment: @morescientistthancoderfornow: I would call that the epsilon rather than the precision, but yes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Right, thank you for giving words to my concern.  Maybe ((currentevent->time)*4) could work in its stead, or the maximum finite double value, though I worry the latter wouldn't be so platform-portable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: 1/0 is positive infinity (which is representable in IEEE 754); as the manpage says, "If x equals y, the functions return y." (y in this case is probably 1/0 or `HUGE_VAL`). Fortunately, the time is rarely infinite.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but why force the trap of `HUGE_VAL` just to tell `nextafter` what direction you want to go?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I guess it's too late here for me to understand the objection. The question, as I understand it, is "how do I correct an event time so that it is not the same as another event time, quickly and without modifying the order much", and the answer, it seems to me, is repeatedly call `nextafter` until you find a value that is not the same as any known event time. Of course, if events can happen at an infinite time, that's not going to work, but the you'll never get around to those events so there is another problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what do you mean by "trapping"?  I did some googling and don't see a straight reference. (Sorry, new to this!)  Could I equally well just use HUGE_VAL directly?  E: You mean a syscall?  Isn't all floating-point arithmetic via syscall?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to ask that, too. You can just use `HUGE_VAL`.

Comment: @rici "epsilon"...that word the mathematicians throw around...yes, fits the context.  Thank you.

Comment: @morescientistthancoderfornow: No, these days most CPUs have builtin floating point. And anyway 1./0. is not a trap (or at least, it is not necessarily a trap; you can set the floating point unit to issue a trap, but unix doesn't). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45c19701a6f9d2cb

Comment: @morescientistthancoderfornow: By the way, don't compute epsilon and then add it repeatedly. Eventually, you will hit a point where epsilon increases, at which point the addition becomes a no-op. You have to call `nextafter` repeatedly. Fortunately, it is *very cheap*.

Comment: @rici Right, I just wanted to bring that out because I asked it too in the question...maybe someone just wants the current epsilon/"precision" for some reason, and they come to this aptly-titled question.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Brendan's comment and @rici's comment, it may be useful to see why an `integer` representation will ultimately decide what the smallest `nextafter` value is and why it is the `integer precision` that controls. `Floats/doubles` are stored in `IEEE-754 single/double precision floating point format` in memory. For every `float` or `double` there is an `integer` representation that corresponds to the `floating point representation`. The `next` available increment, or `nextafter` value is an increment of the value at `bit-0`. The following example illustrates the point for the number `123.456` (example of float shown for space saving, double is simply a larger number of bits involved):

```
Example of next value for   : 123.456

    The float value entered : 123.456001

    As unsigned integer     : 1123477881

    binary value in memory  : 01000010-11110110-11101001-01111001

    next larger int value   : 1123477882

    binary value in memory  : 01000010-11110110-11101001-01111010

    next larger float value : 123.456009
```

In order to find the next possible incremental value, the value in memory is incremented by `1` (or decremented by `1` if the most significant bit is `1` (indicating a negative value)). The results are then translated back into floating point to provide the next possible floating point value. Brendan's point is well taken. By using an integer value, you avoid the necessity of the `nextafter` calculation. But regardless of whether you are using floating point or an integer value, the smallest increment in memory is still the increment (or decrement) of `1` to `bit-0`. For the example above, it is the difference between `123.456001` and `123.456009` (in single precision) as shown below:

```
IEEE-754 Single Precision Floating Point Representations

  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
  |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
  |s|      exp      |                  mantissa                   |

  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
  |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
  |s|      exp      |                  mantissa                   |
```

Hopefully, the visual along with the explanation adds to the understanding. **Note:** there is no actual 'translation' or 'conversion' involved. It is just looking at the same value in memory as either a floating point number, or integer. The only difference to your code is whether you add `1` or add a few more lines of code to find out what the next `floating point` value would be after you add `1`. None of it is processor or time intensive.

Comment: Are you suggesting that for a float, I could cast it as a (4-byte) int, and directly increment it?  Or a similar operation on a double?  (if so, please state so directly)

Comment: Yes, `ivalue = *(unsigned int *)&fvalue;` then `ivalue2 = ivalue + 1;` then `fvalue2 = *(float *)&ivalue2;`. However, there are some camps that howl about doing it this way.

Comment: i.e. ((unsigned int) fvalue)++ ?  Or do they howl even more at that?

Comment: Much more loudly -- I can hear them from here :)

Comment: And for the double, I would cast to @Brendan's uint64_t, because the double precision leaves the mantissa at the end ?

Comment: On x86_64, `unsigned long` is fine (`8-bytes`) and is equivalent to `uint64_t`.

Comment: Your initial suggestion is better because it avoids the complication of an lvalue cast.

Comment: Additional problems with this approach: FP representation is typically sign-magnitude, so for negative values of `fvalue`, incrementing `ivalue` moves toward 0 rather than -INF.  Corner problems with `fvalue = -0, +INF, -INF` and non-typical FP encodings.

Comment: Point well made. Added explanation of increment (or decrement if MSB is `1`). The `-0` and `+INF -INF` are just corner cases to be tested for. (I tried counting to `+INF` once...)